# Add sections to the RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

The RecyclerView is already created, just the list of songs (name and artist) (LinearLayout).
I have to add the sections, so that the songs can be assigned to a **section**.

I already have the SongsAdapter, which uses my `song_layout` in `onCreateViewHolder` function.

What i tried: I created the separate layout for **Sections** (`section_layout`) and implemented the SectionsAdapter.

My question is, is that the right way to go, having separate adapters?
If so, then how do I pass the SongsAdapter into the SectionsAdapter, so that the Song is presented as a Section's child?

Comment: You want to implement multiple view type in this case. Which is already been discussed number of times. Please do some research. This can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type